# Shell script's return value is different in ( normal vs. debugging mode ) execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was solving this "Factorial function in recursive(= getting n! of argument n)" problem. This is the bash shell script code I came up with. I give one integer as an argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script name: RecFact.sh
#
# recursive factorial
factorial(){
if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
    return 1
fi
pro=`expr $pro \* $1`
factorial `expr $1 - 1`
return $pro
}
pro=1
factorial $1
echo "$?"
```

The problem is, when I run it on the terminal with 1~5 as the one argument it needs(e.g. ./RecFact.sh 5), the returned value(like 120 for 5) is correct. 
But when the argument goes above 5, it gets all wrong(like 208 for 6, instead of 720). 
What's really strange is, if I run it in debugging mode(e.g. sh -x ./RecFact.sh 6), the debugger gives the correct value(like 720 for 6) for every input value. 
What could be the reason?

Comment: It is a good practice to add `set -x` in the beginning of script and run the script in usual way to see the debug run of the script.

Answer (score 3):

The error code (which you inspect with $?) is of the range 0-255. And indeed, 720 modulo 256 gives you 208.

Instead of abusing $? you should use a dedicated variable to convey the result.

Comment: It is well documented that the `return` command is used only to return a single byte as the exit code of a function, not to return data. A shell function really is not a function in the usual programming sense.

Answer (score 1):

In normal mode i.e when you are executing **./RecFact.sh 6**  you are actually executing

> bash RecFact.sh 6

since in your script you have `#!/bin/bash`

But in debug mode

> sh -x ./RecFact.sh 6

you are executing using sh. On my system **sh** has a link to **dash**. This may be the case in your system too.

**bash** and **dash** are two different shells , most commands work the same, but they are different. Hence you are seeing two different outputs.

So in your script if you change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh` , it will work fine. 
Also *@employee of the month* is correct. Do not abuse $?